# getting server exception while running Distributed load in jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I am trying to run distributed load on 2 machine [ 50% from master:local host and 50% slave machine]

while running test with slave machine [ set properties file at master machine] and run the scenario in non gui mode

`jmeter -n -t script.jmx -R <slavemachineIP> -l log.jtl`

Getting below exception :

```
Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.jmeter.threads.UltimateThreadGroup (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
```

Remote engines have been started

could you please help with above error

Regards,
perftester

Answer (score 1):

You need to install at least [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) plugin to all remote slaves. It can be done using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Also be aware that JMeter master doesn't produce any load, it only reads the test plan, applies configuration and sends it for execution to remote slaves. So your "master" node won't produce any load unless you run `jmeter-server` on it.

References:

- [Remote Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
- [JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this error is removed, however I tried to run single thread in slave machine and ran command , machine connected but  cmd screen after this "Remote engines have been started
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445"------statement , nothing displayed on screen and Jmeter logs